# How should dependencies of manually installed modules be installed?

Tags: magento2, extensions, composer

We are setting up a Magento 2 store using Composer to manage packages whenever possible. This is working great for us, except that some third-party extensions we have purchased are not available to install via Composer. They require the extension to be manually copied into `app/code`.

However, at least one such manually-installed extension required a separate open source library that was not bundled with the extension. This dependency was specified in the extension's `composer.json` file, but since the extension itself wasn't installed through Composer, it was not picked up by `composer update`.

Thus the question: is there any way to have Composer inspect the dependencies of manually installed extensions living in `app/code`? If not, is the best approach here to simply copy & paste any dependencies into the main project `composer.json`? That's pretty inelegant.

One solution would be to create our own private repository for each of these third-party extensions and then install them via Composer, despite the vendor instructions. We may eventually adopt that approach, but I'm wondering if there are other options.

Comment: You could try the composer merge plugin: https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin. That might work for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @dmatthew. I'll take a look at that. I was hoping for something more automated, but maybe this can *be* automated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If not, is the best approach here to simply copy & paste any dependencies into the main project composer.json? That's pretty inelegant.

Yes, given that the extension is manually copied to app/code, this is the best approach, and yes, this is pretty inelegant.

The real best solution is to **not** copy the extension manually. It already has a composer.json file, so you can install it with composer. Set up a private repository (for example at Bitbucket or on the local filesystem outside of the Magento root), specify it in [`repositories`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md) of your composer.json and then require the module as any other composer module.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. Yes, as I noted in my question, I was aware of the private repository route, but it's a bit of a hassle. I guess it is the "right" answer. It does seem, though, like it should be possible to make Composer look at the `composer.json` files inside `app/code` as if they were inside `vendor`. Maybe I'll submit a PR to `magento/composer` for that.